# Get an Institute List based on my course selection

Tags: android

I would like to show list of institutes based on my Course item click. Example If i click on java button i want to show list of institutes that offers Java. If i click on android then institutes of android. How can I achieve that.? Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to create WEB API for that or search for if any ready api is available or not

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**: Can create a *tablayout*[List of coursed] with a single (activity+fragment)/activity. Fragment will have a recycler view which will show the list of institutes. Based on the tabselection you can refresh the adapter of recycler view given that you already have the data or you are fetching the data on the selection of desired tab where tabs are the list of courses. You can also further extend this to show some details of institute upon click of an item in Recycler view.

**Approach 2**: Create a Recycler view/List View within a recycler view if list of institutes/course is lets say not much but around 10 or else Recycler view inside of recycler view. Outer one will show the list of courses. Upon click of each course another Recycler view expands below per course and shows list of courses.

Your data object could be:

```
{
"data": {
    "java": [
        "Insitute1",
        "Insitute2",
        "Insitute3"
    ],
    "android": [
        "Insitute4",
        "Insitute5",
        "Insitute6"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: I want to show with some static data? Is there any example available to refer

Comment: Try this example